# Stale element exception when using Java streams with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java-8

I am learning Selenium and I am trying out an exercise where I have to select a particular date in a Calendar. I am first collecting all the Web Elements filtered out by classname in a list and then I am trying to iterate over them using Streams API with my needed date as the condition and then I am trying to click it. I am successfully able to select my date but right after that, in the console I can see stale element exception .

I have read some other threads where they suggested that it might have gone to stale because the element is destroyed and then recreated, the other question I have is why some one wants to do that and what is the benefit by destroying and recreating ? I tried doing a driver.navigate().refresh() but It didn't help.

```
driver.get("https://www.path2usa.com/travel-companions");

driver.findElement(By.name("travel_date")).click();

List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("day"));

System.out.println(elements.size());

elements.stream().forEach(p -> {
        if (p.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("24")) {
            p.click();}
    });
```

Expected: The date should be selected and no error thrown in Eclipse console after that.

Actual: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with the usage of forEach Function.

this is how it is working now :

```
driver.findElement(By.name("travel_date")).click();
```

--> This opens the Date Picker.

Now

```
driver.findElements(By.className("day"));
```

--> Returns 42

```
elements.stream().forEach(p -> {
        if (p.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("24")) {
            p.click();}
    });
```

--> Once this finds the element where getText().equalsIgnoreCase("24"), if you notice in the UI, Date picker is closed and selected date is present in the Textbox. Now for the next iteration, p.getText() will cause Stalelement since Date picker is not open.

What you should do is

```
elements.stream().filter(e -> e.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("24")).findAny().get().click();
```

--> this will filter the only element where getText().equalsIgnoreCase("24") and then click it.

Comment: It worked !! I was searching for a "break" equivalent in for Each so that I can come out of the loop but didn't completely understand the filter functionality, this makes it clear, thanks. Regarding my other question as to why the elements are destroyed and recreated and what is the benefit, please provide your thoughts if you are aware.

Comment: There is no creation or destruction actually. its just using the display properties. https://coreui.io/docs/utilities/display/. Please Give a vote for the correct answer , thanks

Comment: Thanks Arun, I marked your answer as correct but I am not able to vote as it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."